Pandas to get data from OECD's revised statistics API
The OECD has changed its statistics API. In the previous version, this structure worked.
oecd = pdmx.Request("OECD")

data = oecd.data(
    resource_id="HH_DASH",
    key="AUS+DEU+ITA+JPN+KOR+GBR+USA+EU27_2020+EMU+G7M+OECD.RGDP_INDEX+RHHGDI_INDEX.Q/all?startTime=2007-Q1&endTime=2023-Q1",
).to_pandas()

df = pd.DataFrame(data).reset_index()

If I use this
> oecd = pdmx.Request("OECD")
> 
> data = oecd.data(
>     resource_id="OECD.SDD.NAD,DSD_HHDASH@DF_HHDASH_CTRY,1.0",
>     key="Q.DEU..?startPeriod=2021-Q3&dimensionAtObservation=AllDimensions",
> ).to_pandas()
> 
> df = pd.DataFrame(data).reset_index() df

The url starts with:
https://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data/
Whereas the actual new url should be:
https://sdmx.oecd.org/public/rest/data/
How can I get it to work

Update the resource ID and key in your code according to new API.

I don't see a question here. If this was something you did to solve your problem, please add the solution as an answer below. You are allowed to answer your own question.

No, I edited the question to include the second block of code to show what I'd tried, and that didn't work. And now I've edited again to repeat the original question.

The OECD helped me to answer this:
url = 'https://sdmx.oecd.org/public/rest/data/OECD.SDD.STES,DSD_STES@DF_CLI/.M.LI...AA...H?startPeriod=2023-02&dimensionAtObservation=AllDimensions&format=csvfilewithlabels'

df = pd.read_csv(url) 

